# Spit out python result in powershell into csv

Tags: python, powershell

Using this script, written in Python, https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/pull/45/commits/e5ec5453233c287cbfe1ecd296ae0ed18c4ce523 Here is my output window for the query.

[image: Access print screen here]

How can I get it to spit out the result as a csv? Important that “dislikes” and “shares” will be separate columns and not added rows as in the display window in powershell.

Comment: Why can't you change the script to print to a CSV instead of standard out?

Comment: You could just push stdout to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of the code is:

```
   for column_header in analytics_query_response.get("columnHeaders", []):
     print "%-20s" % column_header["name"],
   print

   for row in analytics_query_response.get("rows", []):
     for value in row:
       print "%-20s" % value,
     print
```

Basically, you have to open an output file to write to, then instead of prints, call write()

Untested code snippet:

```
   with open(filename.csv, 'w') as csv_out:

     headers = [ch["name"] for ch in analytics_query_response.get("columnHeaders", [])]
     csv_out.write(",".join(headers))

     for row in analytics_query_response.get("rows", []):
       csv_out.write(",".join(row))
```

I did not test this so there may be more problems to overcome.

Comment: I get a reply global name 'filename' is not defined. Any idea why?

Comment: Heh, yes because you need to add the actual name of the file you are printing to. Such as "outputFile.csv"

Comment: Yeah sorry I made that change right after posting. The error I get now is that "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, float found". If I change csv_out.write(",".join(row)) to csv_out.write(",".join([str(value) for value in row]))- it just adds the row values in consecutive columns after the headers. Need them to be created on new rows, below the appropriate header. Any idea how?